# 000-default.conf not found while building docker image of Laravel app on windows

Tags: php, laravel, docker, apache

I am trying to deploy my Laravel application on AWS using docker image by following given tutorial:

```
https://medium.com/@okekedesmond/deploying-containerized-laravel-application-using-aws-ec2-instances-with-docker-and-rds-883e8f6d6245
```

I am stuck at first point while building docker image. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
#  Defining the base image for our project, if you understand how docker images and layers work, this should not be difficult to understand. 
FROM php:7.3-cli
# We need to update the  image and install some import packages
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git curl libpng-dev libonig-dev libxml2-dev
# cleaning packages and install scripts
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# Installing composer which is used to install Laravel
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin –filename=composer
#Creating a configuration file for apache and linking
ADD 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/
RUN ln -sf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf 

#Restarting Apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN service apache2 restart
# Create a work directory and copy all project file into the 
WORKDIR /var/www/app/
COPY . /var/www/app
#Granting permissions to files and folders
RUN chmod -R o+w /var/www/app/storage
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data ./storage
RUN chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
RUN chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
RUN chmod -R 755 /var/www/app/
RUN find /var/www/app/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
# Installing dependencies from laravel package 
RUN composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader --no-ansi --no-interaction --working-dir=/var/www/app
#Running some packages 
RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring pdo pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd opcache
#Running Laravel on docker, because we are using the php-7.3-cli so we have to use a php server in our docker image
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80
EXPOSE 80`
```

It is giving error at step no. 5:

```
Step 5/21 : ADD 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/
ADD failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat 000-default.conf: file does not exist
```

How do I solve it on windows? any help will be appreciated

Comment: Couldn't you just make one manually in the specific directory?

Comment: that's I am asking where should I make this 000-default.conf file? In Laravel project folder? as I am on windows

Comment: I just used apache2 on ubuntu but I think it doesn't differ. The directory to put in is already in your error message. it is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`

Comment: Though I am not 100% sure, maybe you can google it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution is to manually make a new one, here is an example file:

https://gist.github.com/tjtoml/942d696c868b22a25259

And it should be located in:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

It could be that you have to customize it for your needs

Comment: Can you tell me where should I place this file in windows so that while creating image docker will add this file? should I place this file in laravel root folder where Dockerfile is placed?

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing your directory structure. Do you have apache2 installed on your windows machine?

Comment: Got the issue. I think I am not using any wsl2 therefore it is not working

Comment: So it works now? :) I had huge issues with setting up apache2 on ubuntu few days ago, so I am happy when you were able to solve it :)

Comment: yes solved it. I am working first time on docker it is mind twisting game :D

Comment: @Umer I feel that haha. tried working with it few months back on my m1 MacBook, back then it wasn't supported natively and it was such a pain in the ass :D happy you got it working!